# Phonegap - how to change build user

Tags: phonegap-build

I'm just trying to build my first phonegap app. So I created test AdobeID and make a successful built. But on the very same machine I need to use my company AdobeID login, but I cannot find out how to change it. Every time i run phonegap build it uses that test AdobeID that I provided in the first built.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the project from your test ID and log in with your real Adobe ID and then upload it again from scratch, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing phonegap on mobile such as iOS, Android, you need to deactivate the test AdobeID.

Another way is to completely uninstall the app.

However, you can only activate each account 6 times. One of the limit Adobe set.